# Booking 1A berth with a child on Indian Railways

Tags: trains, bookings, indian-railways

I have a question on child 8 yrs old booking on 1st AC, actually we are 2 adults with 1 kid travelling and 
1. shall we only book 2 adults tickets and child is travelling without berth?
2. or book half ticket?
3. or we must book full 1st AC ticket for child?
4. any other option?

Answer (score 3):

[Ministry of Railways Revised Child Fare Rule](http://pib.nic.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid=138458) states:

> Full adult fare will be charged for children of age 5 years and under 12 years of age if for whom full separate berth/seat (in reserved class) is sought at the time of reservation. However, in case full separate berth/seat is not sought for the children of age 5 years and under 12 years of age at the time of reservation,  then half of the adult fare shall continue to be charged subject to the minimum distance for charging. While filling up reservation form, the passenger can indicate their option for requirement of full berth/seat for child or not.
>
> There is no change in the rule for child fare of unreserved tickets i.e. fare for children of 5-12 years for unreserved tickets shall continue to be half of the adult fare subject to the minimum distance for charging.
>
> Children under five years of age will continue to be carried free (without berth) in case of both reserved and unreserved classes.

So for your case if you don't need full seat, you can buy half ticket. But for a [full berth you need to buy a full ticket](http://www.dnaindia.com/money/report-no-more-half-ticket-children-of-5-12-years-of-age-to-pay-full-train-fare-from-april-2016-2152122).